# @instance_variable not available inside a ruby block?

Tags: ruby, scope, instance, block

With the following code:

```
def index
  @q = ""
  @q = params[:search][:q] if params[:search]
  q = @q
  @search = Sunspot.search(User) do
    keywords q
  end
  @users = @search.results
end
```

If @q is used instead of q, the search always returns results for an empty query (""). Why is this?
Is the @q variable unavailable to the do...end block?

Comment: Did you try running with `ruby -W2`?

Comment: Thank you so much @jakeonrails for asking this, I was struggling with that problem for hours. Great answers too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on how the block is being called. If it is called using the `yield` keyword or the `Proc#call` method, then you'll be able to use your instance variables in the block. If it's called using `Object#instance_eval` or `Module#class_eval` then the context of the block will be changed and you won't be able to access your instance variables.

```
@x = "Outside the class"

class Test
  def initialize
    @x = "Inside the class"
  end

  def a(&block)
    block.call
  end

  def b(&block)
    self.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

Test.new.a { @x } #=> "Outside the class"
Test.new.b { @x } #=> "Inside the class"
```

In your case, it looks like `Sunspot.search` is calling your block in a different context using `instance_eval`, because the block needs easy access to that `keywords` method.

Comment: And this is why `instance_eval` is evil. See also [How does instance_eval work and why does DHH hate it?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3071532/#3071983)

Comment: I am having this same problem with Sunspot.  Is there a work around?

Comment: Although littering, you can wrap your instance variable inside methods and call them inside Sunspot's search block.

Comment: FYI, Sunspot supports both `call` and `instance_eval`. If you pass in a block param (like in Jack Zelig's answer), then it will use `call`. Check [code reference here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot/lib/sunspot/util.rb#L98)

Answer (score 7):

As Jeremy says, Sunspot executes its search DSL in a new scope.

In order to use an instance variable in the Sunspot.search block, you'll need to pass it an argument. Something like this should work (not tested):

```
  @q = params[:search][:q] if params[:search]
  @search = Sunspot.search(User) do |query|
    query.keywords @q
  end
  @users = @search.results
```

See here for a better explanation: http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-sunspot/msg/d0444189de3e2725