# Solr not working Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I have this on my view:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row upper_container'>
    <div class='search_container'>
        <%= form_tag deals_path, :method => :get, :class => 'navbar-form navbar-left' do %>  
        <div class='form-group'>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag 'Search', :name => nil %>
      <% end %> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <% @deals.each_with_index do |d, i| %>
    <% if i % 3 == 0 %>
      <div class='row middle_container'>
    <% end %>  
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class='deal_container'>
          <%= d.title %>
          <img src='<%= d.photo %>', class='deal_img'>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% if (i % 3 == 2) || (i == (@deals.length - 1))  %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

this in my controller:

```
class DealsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # @deals = Deal.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @search = Deal.search do  
      fulltext params[:search]  
    end  
    @deals = @search.result
  end

  private
  def deal_params    
    params.require(:deal).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

and this in my model:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base    
  searchable do  
    text :title
  end 
end
```

when I want to do a seach by some word, like 'Treatment', the @deals variable, in the controller is null, but the param is being sent:   `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Treatment"}`

any idea?

Comment: did you perform a data index ? what solr gem are you using ?

Comment: i use the gem sunspot_rails. i did run the reindex, if that is what youre asking

Comment: "What do the logs say?" (hah!) Is Solr server running?

Comment: it is. how do i check the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
query = params[:search]
@search = Deal.search do  
    fulltext query
end  
@deals = @search.result
```

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150483/instance-variable-not-available-inside-a-ruby-block) for details.

Comment: didn't work. after i clicked search, the whole deals list appears

Comment: what does the output from puts params[:search] in the block look like in terminal ?

Comment: nothing. this is the console:
Started GET "/deals?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Tratamiento&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-26 22:48:34 -0200
Processing by DealsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Treatment", "commit"=>"Search"}
  Deal Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals"
  Rendered deals/index.html.erb within layouts/application (50.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 788ms (Views: 780.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms | Solr: 0.0ms)

Comment: Ok can you please add puts @query just after the puts params and send me the output?

Comment: there's no output. clearly, it's not excecuting the search block. Any idea why?

Comment: No its executing just not passing variables to the block try puts "called" I have solved that once before just need to remember how

Comment: if i put the puts after the line '@search = Deal.search do' nothing gets printed. But if i placed it before, it does. I guess it-s not being called

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150483/instance-variable-not-available-inside-a-ruby-block)